# Creating new layers and DXF export

Tags: qgis, dxf

I have a small .OSM map which has some rules set up based of whether it's deemed a primary road, secondary road, path etc. What I would like to do is branch each one of these out to its own layer for exporting to a DXF. I've tried to duplicate the layer and removed the conditional formatting but when I export the DXF it still contains all of the data.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Ive done it now. Using the select features by value you can narrow the selection down with the different options.